# Java regular expression works on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: java, regex

I built i java class names `Scanner`.
This class open files and apply three regular expressions on them.

On my Linux system all three patterns are working fine. On Windows only two of them and after hours i really don't know why...

These are my three patterns

```
private static final Pattern TILE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("<xyz:tile\\sfilename=\"(\\S+)\"");
private static final Pattern VALUE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("<xyz:value\\sxyz:name=\"(\\S+)\"[\\sxyz:type=\"(\\S)\"]*>");
private static final Pattern IF_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("<xyz:if-visible\\sxyz:name=\"(\\S+)\">");
```

`VALUE_PATTERN` and `IF_PATTERN` are ok.
`TILE_PATTERN` does not work...

This is my method:

```
public static List<String> scanForTiles(TemplateModel template) {
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(template.getPath())) {
        List<String> includes = new ArrayList<>();
        stream.map(TILE_PATTERN::matcher)
            .flatMap(matcher -> {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                while (matcher.find()) {
                    list.add(matcher.group(1));
                }
                return list.stream();
            })
            .forEach(includes::add);
        return includes;
    }catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    return null;
}
```

Example code of my template:

```
<!-- NOT ok -->
<xyz:tile filename="containers/mainLogin.html">
<!-- OK -->
<xyz:if-visible xyz:name=".variable">
```

Comment: Add example of the String that is matched on Linux and not matched on Windows.

Comment: How do you process the `VALUE_PATTERN` and `IF_PATTERN`?

Comment: One (unrelated?) problem with your RE is that (at least) Windows allows spaces in file names. Thus `\S` won't work for all file names.

Comment: Example added; @SubOptimal the same way. I have two (same) functions just with the others pattern variable

Comment: Regex for XML? Can't you just use xquery or something similar?

Comment: Are the input files the same? If I use you provided code and `NOT ok` line the code is working well. `includes` contains the String `containers/mainLogin.html`.

Comment: Yep all the input files are html files. The main class passes the `TemplateModel` at first to the method for the `VALUE_PATTERN` and `IF_PATTERN` and at least to these method.. By the way.. the window systems gets a Jar file of the software - could this be a problem? The Jar file on Linux works fine too...

Comment: Didn't you forgot to add closing char > at the end of TILE_PATTERN? VALUE and IF string have it.

Comment: im using windows i have tried your code and it works i have put "<xyz:tile filename="containers/mainLogin.html">" and it could retrieve for me "containers/mainLogin.html"

Comment: @Tobias Have you already checked that for `TILE_PATTERN` the `Files.lines(template.getPath())` returns the lines on Windows? If not, the pattern isn't the problem.

Comment: @JuanMendes the files are not XML valid. Every parser throws an exception.. ;)

Comment: @SubOptimal I tried the code on another Windows systems... it works.. Seems there are something wrong with the first windows machine. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On notable difference between linux and windows are new lines. In linux the character for new lines is \n (line feed) in windows new lines are representd by two characters \r\n (carriage return and line feed). 
Moreover regular expressions by default don't match on multiple lines and normally the new line character acts as the $ or end line matcher, this may be one of the reasons your regular expressions behaves differently in both operating systems.

Comment: Your comment is right. But `Files.lines(...)` and the underlying `BufferedReader.readline()` takes care about the line ends and return a list of lines, independent of the lineend character.